# How can I get the battery remaining value in hours in Android?

Tags: android, battery

I want to get the battery remaining idle time and also audio, video, Wi-Fi and talking remaining time in Android. And time should be in hours and minutes, not in percentage.

The remaining time means the current value of the battery to how long it will work that I want to have in hours and minutes.

If I'm playing audio continually then how long will the battery work? The same for video, Wi-Fi and talking.

Comment: May be I miss understood the question. Can you precise what is "idle time" for battery,audio video .... Does your question is about "Deep Sleep" ?

Comment: @EmmanuelDevaux i am facing same problem  . when my device is in deep sleep or in doze mode work manger and any other time specific not working for me . if you have any of soln . you are welcome

Answer (score -2):

Check out the BatteryManager class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

Should help you out some.

Comment: I read this and with the help of this i calculated the level of battery and whether its charging or not